# How to cover rest of tableview with the same background as the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView where I have a plain Image for the cell.

I have a search-bar in the header. Whenever I search, the number of cell show the search results. The problem is that, if number of search results cannot cover the whole height of the screen then, we see the background behind the tableview.

I want the tableView to show the same height throughout irrespective of number of cells.

Also I want to show the same translucent background Image I show for cell to be shown when cells are not their in the background.

If I set this as an ImageView behind the tableView then, thru the cells, everything seems darker.

Comment: Did you find the answer for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the background color of the table view for a pattern image.

```
UIColor *backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
```

Note that the background image will not be stretched but tiled if the size of the image is different from the table view's size (frame).

The other option is to add a background image view to the table and set the table view's background to clear.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
[imageView setFrame:self.tableView.frame]; 
self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an UIImageView and set the image as your cell background image. Use this imageview to set the backgroundView property of your UITableView. Hope this works.

Comment: but that image is slightly transparent, if i set a background of the tableview as well. Wont that look darker through the cell than the normal background ?